# How to use JS confirm within a conditional PHP statement?

Tags: php, javascript

PHP is executed first before JS, but is there an easy way to output a confirmation dialog (like Javascript confirmation) if the data is not empty like in this conditional PHP statement:

```
<?php
if (!empty($data)) {

//data is not empty
//Ideally I want to show a confirmation dialog in this part to the user
//to confirm if the user wants to overwrite the existing data

//If the user confirms
//Overwrite the existing data here

} else {

//data is empty,proceed to other task
//don't show any dialog

}
```

I don't want to add another form to the user, just a simple confirmation dialog like the JS confirm. Or is there a PHP replacement function for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to separate the data and the code, so I like to create a JS variable from PHP

```
// I always use json_encode when creating JS variables from PHP to avoid
// encoding issues with new lines and quotes.
var isDataEmpty = <?php echo json_encode(empty($data)); ?>;

if (!isDataEmpty) {
   if (confirm("Some message")) {
      overwriteExistingData();
   }
} else {
   // proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your PHP code write JavaScript like the following:

```
<script type="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?php
    if (!empty($data)) {
    ?>
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to overwrite?");
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    // Data is empty
    <?php
    }
    ?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should keep the mixing of PHP and JS to a minimum, see my answer, JS and PHP interact only in one line.

Answer (score 0):

see the code below

```
<?php
if (!empty($data)) {
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.confirm("data is not empty")</script>';

//data is not empty
//Ideally I want to show a confirmation dialog in this part to the user
//to confirm if the user wants to overwrite the existing data

//If the user confirms
//Overwrite the existing data here

} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.confirm("data is empty here")</script>';

//data is empty,proceed to other task
//don't show any dialog

}
```

Comment: Using echo to generate HTML is very hard to read. You're unnecessarily coding the script tag in two places (and making the mistake of adding `language="javascript"` in two places